# Mobile nav menu gets stuck to the top of the screen after scroll

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm developing a site for a client on Wordpress using a theme I'm modifying and I've been making a bunch of edits to the mobile nav menu and somewhere along the line I messed something up and now after scrolling to the bottom of the mobile nav half of it gets stuck to the top of the screen.

Current site: http://test.kevinwallace.io/

It was working right, and I've tried to undo and troubleshoot all the changes I've made and nothing is working. Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Edit: So I just tried a clean version of the theme and apparently it's always had this behavior. Is there a way to simply close the mobile nav when the user scrolls past?

Answer (score 0):

you dont want that scroll ?
 iam not understand 
  if you dont want scroll mean

```css
@media (max-width: 767px)
hotmagazine_sty…ver=4.7.2:6304
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 220px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

please remove this code 
http://test.kevinwallace.io/wp-content/themes/hotmagazine/css/hotmagazine_style.css?ver=4.7.2 
line  6304
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvl7D.png)